# Is Multicollinearity the reason behind the poor performace of my ANN model for regression?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, regression, pca

So I was working on a tribology dataset to predict residual depth.It is a regression problem but when I saw the correlations values between the independent variables they were  more than 0.9 so OLS and linear regression were out of the picture an I went ahead with other models like lasso ,ridge, XGB and other tree based models. and the results were pretty good R2 of around 0.98 and and MAPE varied b/w 6%-3%.

I was just curious so I tried to fit a deep neural network on the same data but the results were pretty bad MAPE of more than 50%. I tried tinkering the depth and nuber of neurons but there was no improvement.I was wondering if it was the Multicollinearity that screwed up my model or should I go back and pickup my deep learning book again.

this is my dataset[image]

[DATASET](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eFgEhKtC1xdvbZzChepAgCahZ-NbVRD2/view?usp=sharing)

Measured Fn (N), Pd (µm) are the features and residual is the target variable
[image]